# Deleting a Site

Tags: import, site-deletion

Currently I have a structure as below:

- http://thesite
- http://thesite/my (MySite)

I need to delete and re-create the site "thesite" but I don't want to lose the site "my".

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I see you've already accepted an answer, but just to clarify is /My a site within thesite site collection, or is /My a managed path to the My Site host site collection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there are many such cases, then I would suggest you to use Metalogic Migration tools, if this is one of the case then , following should help.

Take a full backup of the subsite (http://thesite/my) (MySite)

```
stsadm -o backup -url "http://thesite/my (MySite)" -filename "<<add the file path>>"
```

Delete the sitecollection in central admin, take a backup of whole site collection before u delete , to be on safer side :)

recreate the root sitecollection (http://thesite) the way you want and restore the subsite back

```
stsadm -o restore -url "http://thesite/my (MySite)" -filename "<<add the file path>>"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If we're assuming "/my (mysite)" is a site collection (using an explicit managed path of /my), there is no need to back it up as it is an independent site collection from the root site collection. Alternatively, if we assume /my is a site within the site collection, stsadm -o backup will not work; the export operation is needed

Answer (score 1):

You could save the "my" site as a Site Template (including content) and then importing the resulting .stp/.wsp into the Site Template Gallery of the new "thesite".  Then, create a site based on that template.

That would work if the "my" site is not heavy on data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you do not have much content in your site is to use:

Site Actions > Site Settings > Content and Structure (http://thesite/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx)

Right-click the site and select Move